# How to "Tab" and "Down Arrow" in Internet Explorer Using Visual Basic

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, internet-explorer-9

Does anybody know how to emulate the tab and down arrow buttons in Visual Basic?  I am using the Internet Explorer object in VB

Comment: You could try using SendKeys. Although if you update your question and explain your goal, someone may offer a solution better suited to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendkeys did the trick

```
Dim numberoftabs as Long
Dim numberofdownarrows1 as long

numberoftabs = yourvalue
numberofdownarrows1 = yourvalue

Application.SendKeys "{TAB " & numberoftabs & "}", True
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN " & numberofdownarrows1 & "}", True
Application.SendKeys "~", True
```

Comment: If you could show the code you used, it might be of better help to future googlers.